# Returning list of users someone is following (over 200)

Tags: php, soundcloud

I've been working on this **SoundCloud** website for awhile now and have just got into creating a stream page alternative that will display on our website. I have stumbled into an issue however and I'm sure it's an easy solution I'm just now figuring out how 2 achieve the proper output.

```
$user_ID = $_GET['id'];
$sc = curl_init();
curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/'.$user_ID.'/followings?client_id='.$client_ID.'&page_size=200&cursor=1419617528000');
curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($sc);
curl_close($sc);
$content = json_decode($output, true);
```

As you can see above the code currently is suppose to display up to 400 users in which someone is following, however when we do the following 2 return all of the content which is being displayed on that link.

```
echo "<pre>";
  print_r($content);
echo "</pre>";
```

It appears that it caps at only 200 results ( *which is really not that good we need 2 find an alternative 2 display the full amount of users someone is following.* ) at the bottom of th page it displays another message.

```
 [199] => Array
            (
                [avatar_url] => http://a1.sndcdn.com/images/default_avatar_large.png?1485508269
                [id] => 72067899
                [kind] => user
                [permalink_url] => http://soundcloud.com/berthalie30
                [uri] => https://api.soundcloud.com/users/72067899
                [username] => berthalie30
                [permalink] => berthalie30
                [last_modified] => 2016/04/06 21:53:03 +0000
                [first_name] => 
                [last_name] => 
                [full_name] => 
                [city] => 
                [description] => 
                [country] => 
                [track_count] => 0
                [public_favorites_count] => 0
                [followers_count] => 21
                [followings_count] => 89
                [plan] => Free
                [myspace_name] => 
                [discogs_name] => 
                [website_title] => 
                [website] => 
                [reposts_count] => 32
                [comments_count] => 0
                [online] => 
                [likes_count] => 0
                [playlist_count] => 6
            )

    )

[next_href] => https://api.soundcloud.com/users/24537746/followings?client_id=XXXX&page_size=200&cursor=1406526915000
```

However, even using this method does nothing (*even though I'm more then certain the user I am testing with has more then 200 users he's following*.)

---

**EDIT** : Someone [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated) is having the same issue, how ever I don't understand the comment solution on how 2 prevent it from happening..